# missing rails gem: zlib not found on snow leopard, but shows in ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, installation, zlib

Trying to start development on a snow leopard machine. Have reinstalled and built ruby and ruby on rails via

[hivelogic post](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/)

Prior to sorting out my own rails app, I created a test app, and all the expected files showed up. But when I try to run it I get

> Missing the Rails 2.2.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.2.2 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

Trying to do so results in

> /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- zlib (LoadError)

Prior to installing the ruby and ruby on rails versions, I had run ports to install zlib with

> port install zlib +universal

on the assumption that this might get around architecture problems

and checking I see:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10]
```

> $ rails -v Rails 2.2.2

```
$ port list | grep 'zlib'
zlib                           @1.2.3          archivers/zlib
hs-zlib                        @0.5.0.0        devel/hs-zlib
p5-compress-raw-zlib           @2.021          perl/p5-compress-raw-zlib
p5-io-zlib                     @1.10           perl/p5-io-zlib
php5-zlib                      @5.3.0          php/php5-zlib
py25-zlib                      @2.5.4          python/py25-zlib
```

so I'm stuck. the victim of my own incompetencer. The original objective was to get rmagick running, and somewhere along the way I'm pretty sure my ruby/RoR setup got hosed. Haven't tested it on the original Snow Leopard install, i can't say, but the machine is very new, upgraded the first day I owned it to 10.6.

The eventual objective includes getting all this running under Mongrel, with rmagick and google-geocode. The production server is running earlier versions of all of this under Solaris and doing so fine, as was my previous machine's 10.5 setup. And yes, I've tried installing the latest Developer Tools and XCode, both from the Apple site and the SL install DVD

Am I better off starting from scratch, or repairing from here... and where are starting points for either?

Comment: What happens if you type "require 'zlib'" in irb?

Comment: if its any consolation im in exactly the same predicament

Comment: Ended up rebuilding from scratch.

Comment: and NOT using MacPorts, which seems to have been the original source of my problems. If I can reconstruct exactly what I did, I'll post. But basically, scrape and start again. To my surprise, after doing so, even rmagick seems to be working.